# HTML5 / jQuery Parallax Effect -- "background-size" issue

Tags: jquery, html, parallax

So I've built a site using [this tutorial](http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/blog/code-tutorials/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/) and have encountered a minor bug.

I have a set of photos (sized around 700-800px) that I would like to use as background-images for each  "section" of the vertical page.

I'm having no trouble loading the images through the CSS, but when I try to re-size the images to be full-screen using the following command(s)

```
background-size:cover;
```

OR

```
background-size:100%;
```

The jQuery scroll animation becomes very choppy / laggy.

And to clarify, when the images load at their normal size (and do not fill the entire window), the page scrolls very smoothly.

Any suggestions? Different ways to resize the images using CSS? Any way to optimize the jQuery script to prevent the sluggishness?

Comment: Interesting -- I've never used or known about `background-size`, but that's probably because it isn't supported in IE7/8 and I've always had to keep those browsers in mind.